# Getting error while creating bean

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Please, help me fix this problem.

> [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to
>   requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]

```
my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>       
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">Kate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Ant0987M@+</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <mapping class="com.springapp.mvc.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

User.java

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    } 
}
```

UserController.java

package com.springapp.mvc;

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyLogger");

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        logger.info("in meth listUsers");
        logger.trace("trace in listUsers");

        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepository.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {

        logger.info("in meth addUser");

        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/"/* + userRepository.getClass().getName()*/;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{userId}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {

        logger.info("in meth deleteUser");

        userRepository.delete(userRepository.findOne(userId));

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/users", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String listUsersJson(ModelMap model) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();
        for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
            JSONObject userJSON = new JSONObject();
            userJSON.put("id", user.getId());
            userJSON.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
            userJSON.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
            userJSON.put("email", user.getEmail());
            userArray.put(userJSON);
        }
        return userArray.toString();
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
 package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends Repository <User, Long> {

   public <S extends User> S save(S entity);

    public User findOne(Long aLong);

    public List<User> findAll();

    public void delete(User entity);

}
```

Comment: where did you put hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Comment: MySpringApp\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration, Remove the **hibernate.** from the config

```
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">Kate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Ant0987M@+</property>
```

Corrected configuration

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company</property>
        <property name="connection.username">Kate</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Ant0987M@+</property>
```